# Trying to create a 2d array by inserting characters retrieved from file stream

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, scanf, fgets

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ROW 10
#define COLUMN 20
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE* fptr;
  char grid[ROW][COLUMN];
  int i ,j;
  fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  for ( i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
    for ( j = 0; j< COLUMN; j++){

     fscanf(fptr,"%c",&grid[i][j]);
    }


  }
  for(i = 0; i< ROW; i++){
    for(j = 0; j< COLUMN; j++){
      printf("%c",grid[i][j]);
    }
  }



  return(0);
}
```

This is my input file:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is my output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but it should look like the input file itself. I don't know what I did wrong as I feel very incompetent and I need it for an assignment. Thing is the input file needs to be stored as a 2d array because later on the element of the array will be used to compare for creating COnways game of life.

Comment: Read the [man page for `fscanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) carefully with regards to `%c`: "The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. ".

Comment: When you encounter problems like this the best thing to do is to run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements. Specifically for this case, check what is being stored in `grid[i][j]` for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

space and newline is also read by your fscanf, you can skip it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ROW 10
#define COLUMN 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  FILE* fptr;
  char grid[ROW][COLUMN];
  int i ,j;
  fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");

for ( i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
for ( j = 0; j< COLUMN; j++){

           fscanf(fptr,"%c ",&grid[i][j]);
        }

            fscanf(fptr,"\n");
       }

 for(i = 0; i< ROW; i++){
 for(j = 0; j< COLUMN; j++){
     printf("%c ",grid[i][j]);
     }

     printf("\n");
     }


 return(0);
}
```

It is not good practice to decide Row size, column size before reading file. You can make  first line in the input file contains the row size,column size.